# Can not get OOP to work correctly - Shopping Cart, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, shopping-cart

I can not seem to find any fault in this shopping-cart, but it is not displaying correctly.. I saw this YouTube video, and tried the code from there (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlwMBtx0YMQ), but it had MySQL instead of MYSQL PDO; so I converted to PDO instead. I am echoing the class from another page to display the HTML-code. Yes, I am new to this..

> The code is translated from Norwegian to English:

```
<?php
    class shoppingCart {
        // This function works as it should it seems like
        function writeShoppingCart() {
            $cart = $_SESSION["cart"];
            if (!$cart) {
                return "0 products";
            } else {
                $products = explode(",",$cart);
                $number = (count($products) > 1) ? "s" : "";
                return "<a href='cart.php'>".count($products)." Products ".$number."";
            }
        }
        // But this function is not working as it should (?)
        function showCart() {
            $cart = $_SESSION["cart"];
            if ($cart) {
                $products = explode(",",$cart);
                $content = array();
                // FAULT HERE MAYBE ?
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                    $content[$product] = (isset($content[$product])) ? $content[$product]+1 : 1;
                }
                $output[] = '<form action="cart.php?action=update" method="POST" id="cart"';
                $output[] = '<table>'; // This was corrected by "jeyoung" (">")
                // HERE ? $content .. I THINK
                foreach ($content as $productID=>$qty) {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID = ".productID;
                    // FAULT HERE ....?
                    echo " WORKS HERE 1 "; // From here and down the code stops displaying ...
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    echo " WORKS HERE 2 "; // This is just check-marks to make it easier to find the fault ..
                    $user_data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
                    echo " WORKS HERE 3 ";
                    extract($user_data);

                    $output[] = '<tr>';
                    $output[] = '<td><a href="cart.php?action=delete&id='.$productID.'" > Delete </a></td>';
                    $output[] = '<td>'.$productName.'</td>';
                    $output[] = '<td>NOK '.$PriceNOK.',-</td>';
                    $output[] = '<td><input type="text" name="qty'.$productID.'" value='.$qty.' size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>';
                    $output[] = '<td> NOK '.($PriceNOK * $qty).',-</td>';
                    $totalCost += $PriceNOK * $qty;
                    $output[] = '</tr>';
                    echo " WORKS HERE 4 ";
                }
                $output[] = '</table>';
                $output[] = '<p> Total: <strong>NOK '.$totalCost.',-</strong></p>'; // NOK = Norwegian Kroner (currency)
                $output[] = '<button type="submit">Update Cart</button>';
                $output[] = '</form>';
            } else {
                $output[] = '<p>Cart is empty.</p>'; // Cart empty
        }
            return join('',$output);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

[image: This is what is displaying .. Supposed to be price, all products etc.]

Comment: Sorry but this site is not suitable for posting a blob of code and asking what is wrong with it

Comment: Also, source code in non English is generally an extremely bad idea. For reasons this post demonstrates beautifully, even with your translation, you create a fairly high barrier to entry for anyone not speaking your language to help you. (Or if your team expands and get's international colleague's etc.)

Comment: Agreed. Additionally, it even takes effort to translate this with your provided "dictionary". Noone likes effort, we are programmers. The easier you make it for us, the more we are likely to help!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes. I will translate the whole code to english; sorry... As a neewbie, I do not know what else to do than to post a "blob of code". I have tried allot to find the error, and want to make it work, but do not know coding that much (should properly learn more first hehe).

Comment: Are there any errors shown?

Comment: No, I have tried turning error-handling on, but can not seem to get it to work.. I only get the famous 500-error. But currently, I just get the "writeShoppingCart()" to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your function

```
    function showCart() {
        $cart = $_SESSION["cart"];
        if ($cart) {
            $output = explode(",",$cart);
            $content = array();
            // FAULT HERE MAYBE ?
            foreach ($products as $product) {
```

Your `foreach` used `$products` but you do not have this variable. You need to assign that variable the way you do in the first function. Instead of

```
$output = explode(",",$cart);
```

use

```
$products = explode(",",$cart);
```

The "s" at the beginning of the code is not a typo, it should change product into products if needed.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that spelling.. The translation was wrong, it is supposed to be `$products = explode(",",$cart);` as you said, and that is what I got in my original code, only in norwegian; but is still not working! Aha, yes, now I know that with the "s".

Comment: I added a picture of what I get.

Comment: So obviously your query is the trouble. There is no `$conn` specified. You should check that.

Comment: I have specified that in another php-dokument that is required; but it is something wrong with the query. I figured out more in detail what is wrong, so I will delete this post and post a new one with the line of code that does not work.

Comment: Hello RST, I figured out I need to define $conn inside the class, and not only outside the class... I did not know this was necessary!

Comment: Glad it is working, but I actually told you that 3 days ago.

Comment: Hehe, yes. I thought I had defined it, but had to define it inside the class also. I set your answer as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On this line, `$produksjon[] = '<table';`, the tag is not closed properly.

It should be `$produksjon[] = '<table>';`.

Comment: It did not help the problem with displaying the code, but it did correct that error!

Comment: What are you talking about? That was the error in your code.

Comment: Not the only one.

Comment: Not the main one that is causing "stuff" to not be displayed!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to define $conn inside the ShoppingCart-class itself. I had only defined it outside! Did not know this was necessary.